# Popen is no able to process a command that runs in shell

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have already read the previous questions posted on the same argument but I really haven't figured it out yet.

I am trying to run a command that works without issues from the command line :

```
xyz@klm:~/python-remoteWorkspace/PyLogParser/src:18:43>ush -o PPP -p PRD -n log 'pwd'
6:43PM PPP:prd:lgsprdppp:/ama/log/PRD/ppp
```

but when I do the same in python I always get errors :

```
stringa = Popen(["ush -o PPP -p PRD -n log 'pwd'"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Here the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "getStatData.py", line 134, in <module>
    retrieveListOfFiles(infoToRetList)   File "getStatData.py", line 120, in retrieveListOfFiles
    stringa = Popen(["ush -o PPP -p PRD -n log 'pwd'"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate()[0]   File "/opt/python-2.6-64/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)   File "/opt/python-2.6-64/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1092, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried also different solutions like

```
stringa = Popen(["ush", "-o", "PPP", "-p" "PRD", "-n", "log", '"pwd"'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

but nothing seems to work. I have also tried to put the absolute path to ush but nothing... 
Can somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance, AM.

EDIT : 
I have a strange thing happening, when I do

```
which ush
```

I get

```
ush: aliased to nocorrect /projects/aaaaaaa/local/ush/latest/ush.py
```

But why is it working then ???

!!! Thank you all for the answers !!!

Comment: Does `ush -o PPP -p PRD -n log 'pwd'` work from the command line?

Comment: Sure, the response is here above PPP:prd:lgsprdppp:/ama/log/PRD/ppp

Comment: Please improve the formatting. When inserting code blocks, use the `{}`.

Comment: What is your `import` statement like?

Comment: Hi, here below my import ...
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ush` on your system is an alias, popen won't work. popen requires an executable file as the first parameter: either an absolute path or the name of something that is in your PATH.

Comment: It's surely an alias, maybe is for that reason ... What if I make a shell script and at its inside I call the ush ?? And than I call the shell script from python, should it work ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Popen(["ush", "-o", "PPP", "-p", "PRD", "-n", "log", "pwd"])
```

should be right.  The extra quoting around `'pwd'` in the shell command makes it a single argument, but the quotes aren't actually passed along.  Since you're already splitting the arguments, leave the extra quotes out.

---

Apparently (in an update from OP) `ush` is a shell alias.  Thus, it only expands in the shell; anywhere else, it won't work.  Expand it yourself:

```
Popen(["nocorrect", "/projects/aaaaaaa/local/ush/latest/ush.py",
       "-o", "PPP", "-p", "PRD", "-n", "log", "pwd"])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering stringa = Popen(["ush", "-o", "PPP", "-p", "PRD", "-n", "log", "pwd"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE).communicate()[0] gets the same result 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory