# submodules.Popen refuses to run a command even though os.system works fine

Tags: python, gruntjs, subprocess, popen

Whenever I run this script:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['grunt', 'build'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I consistently get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_grunt_fail.py", line 3, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(['grunt', 'build'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

However, `grunt` is definitely installed, since I can run `grunt build` from the command line without any issues, as well as run `os.system("grunt build")` inside the program.

Given this, why does `os.system()` work while `subprocess.Popen()` won't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popen is no able to process a command that runs in shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512059/popen-is-no-able-to-process-a-command-that-runs-in-shell)

Comment: @aruisdante Not a duplicate of that answer (in fact, I looked at that one first); that problem was solved by noting that the thing which the OP was trying to run was an alias. However, in this case `grunt` is definitely the name of something on the system path (`grunt.bat`), not an alias.

Comment: I asked [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137556/windows-subprocess-popen-a-batch-file-without-shell-true) about a year ago. I think the `cwd` keyword argument in the comments worked.

Comment: @Blender Thank you - I didn't read that one. It may not be applicable, though: to quote a comment on your question, "The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable."

Comment: @Blender After adding `cwd`, the error becomes "Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt") SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"